# Possible to make a list item appear first via css?

Tags: css, listview, jquery-mobile

I have a jquery mobile listview, and I'd like to make one of the li items **appear** first in the list via css **without** moving the li item in the code. I don't want the li item to be in a fixed position (in other words, I do want it to scroll with the list). I just want it to appear as though it were the first li item.

Here is the code for the list (just 2 li items). So I'm wondering how I could style the second li to appear first.

```html
<div data-role="page" data-theme="c"> 
<div data-role="content">
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="false"><li>
    <a href="http://domain.com/1XyK?id=1117448578">
    <img src="https://domain.com/moreicon/EN/bundle-loseweight.png" />
    <h2>Healthy Weight Loss</h2>
    <p>Now includes Mindful Eating!</p>
    <span class="ui-li-count">NEW</span>
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="http://domain.com?id=977040364">
    <img src="https://domain.com/moreicon/EN/bundle-top10.png" />
    <h2>Our Top 10 Apps!</h2>
    <p>Save BIG on our chart toppers!</p>
    <span class="ui-li-count">SAVE</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Post the code you have so far and we'll see how we can assist

Comment: Why don't you move it on the DOM ?

Comment: It's not dynamically generated. It's just a static list styled to look like a jquery mobile listview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility, if your browser support allows for it, is Flexbox. This allows you to control the order of elements by using the `order` property on the child.

For example, if your HTML is:

```
<ul>
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second</li>
</ul>
```

Then, you can style the UL as a columnar flexbox in CSS:

```
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

And you can assign a negative `order` to the child you want to bring to the top:

```
ul li:nth-of-type(2) {
  order: -1;
}
```

Working example: http://codepen.io/honzie/pen/oLxENz

Comment: I wasn't aware of Flexbox, thanks! If I understand the nth-of-type property correctly, I'm not sure this solution accounts for different positions of the li item I'm trying to move. This list of 2 items was just an example. In the actual scenario, there would be 15+ items, and the item I'm trying to move will vary (and so will its native position in the list). Can this solution be used in a non-relative manner?

Comment: I think I figured out how to adapt your solution. I just changed the li style to a class and assigned that class to the list item I want to move. And the order property (-1) makes it appear first. Thanks!

Comment: Your adaptation is spot on. I stepped away from keys. Class-based likely makes more sense in a real-world solution than the contrived `nth-child` selector. I'm glad this worked for you.

Comment: Set the li's order to -1 to move it to the start (as per above), and set it to a very large value (ie 99) to move it to the end and keep it at the end when new items are added. So long as the total number of items is less than 99, for example.